# Understanding ARIMA results

Tags: time-series, arima, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I have the following results on my ARIMA forecast and was wondering how I can create an equation out of my coefficients?

I am using `auto_arima` provided by the `pmdarima` library in Python.

[image]
Best regards

Comment: I can't identify the software you are using, so I personally won't be able to help. It would be useful if you added information about your software. We don't even know whether it fits a "true" SARIMAX model, or a regression with SARIMA errors. [There is a difference.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.